# Google Sheets Formula Converting My { into %7D & %7B

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a URL formula in sheets. My formula has { in it, but sheets keeps converting it to %7D when clicked. How do I make it stop doing that?

FORMULA

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE( "https://xyz.xyz.com/test/flow/workflowid/form/link?formData={questionid:",
A2,
"questionid2:",
B2,
"}"))
```

OUTPUT I GET

https://xyz.xyz.com/test/flow/workflowid/form/link?formData= %7B questionid:question,questionid2:question2 %7D

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
="https://xyz.xyz.com/test/flow/workflowid/form/link?formData="&
 CHAR(123)&"questionid:"&A2&"questionid2:"&B2&CHAR(125)
```